# What is the Lebesgue measure of zero-dimensional space?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, lebesgue-measure

I learnt about the concept of the Lebesgue measure some time ago, and one question was always confusing to me (and was never answered).

**What is the Lebesgue measure of zero-dimensional space?**

What I know is that the Lebesgue measure is defined as the standard way of measuring a subset of some Euclidean space $R^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of the space.

This means that:

- The standard way to measure the subset (a “part” that is well-defined in the space) of a line ($R^1$) is length; makes sense
- The standard way to measure the subset of a plane ($R^2$) is area; makes sense
- The standard way to measure the subset of a solid space ($R^3$) is volume; makes sense
- And this continues for dimensions $d > 3$ in some $R^d$.

But when It comes to $R^0$, there are two questions that often come unanswered and can really confuse you:

- **Q1** If Lebesgue measure is defined on $n$-dimensional space as a standard way to assign measure to a proper subset of $R^n$, how would we define the Lebesgue measure of $0$-dimensional space? This amounts to measuring the subset of a point, which kind of doesn’t make sense in my mind.
- **Q2** I think we define the dimension of some $S^n$, where $S$ can be some space, as the number of coordinates (also: coordinate axis) needed to specify the location of some point in/on $S_n$. This makes sense for $1$-dimensional space, as you just need one number on the number line to find a location of a point on the number line, and for $2$-dimensional space, you need two: the $x$ and $y$-axis to specify a point on a plane. Their logic continues for higher dimensions. But how does it make sense that we need “no coordinates” to specify a point on a point?

Or is all of this above stuff nonsense and a point is just zero length? If that’s a case, why would we assign a new dimension to something that can be measured in a Lebesgue measure defined in another dimension?

I couldn’t find any useful information anywhere else for these questions, hence

Any help or clarification is appreciated!

Comment: It would be the counting measure ($\Bbb R^0$ is simply a point, but more generally, "zero dimensional spaces" are discrete spaces).

Comment: There is a way to make an interesting question out of what you wrote but you would have to learn about Hausdorff measures, Hausdorff dimension and covering (topological) dimension.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you elaborate on what question you could make out of it?

Comment: You could ask for instance if a compact subset $K$ of the Euclidean $n$-space $E^n$ of zero topological (covering) dimension necessarily has zero Lebesgue measure. (The answer would be negative.) Or you can ask the same question where $K$ has zero Hausdorff dimension. (The answer would be positive.) None of these questions are deep by any means but being able to ask them means that you understand what are meaningful notions of dimension beyond counting the number of coordinates (or degrees of freedom).

Comment: To say that we need "zero coordinates" to specify a point in $\mathbb R^0$ is just an informal way of saying that the dimension of the vector space $\mathbb R^0$ is $0$ (the empty set is a basis of $\mathbb R^0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that most authors who define the Lebesgue measure for $\mathbb R^n$ are not thinking about the case $n=0$. But if you do define it for $n=0$ (which I think is sensible), then the zero-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb R^0$ is $1$ according to standard mathematical conventions about vacuous/trivial cases.

One standard way to define the Lebesgue outer measure in $\mathbb R^n$ is as follows. First, we define a *closed rectangle* $R$ in $\mathbb R^n$ to be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ of the form $[a_1,b_1]\times \dots\times [a_n,b_n]$, with $a_i\le b_i$ for each $i$. The "volume" $\DeclareMathOperator{\vol}{vol}\vol(R)$ of $R$ is defined to be
$$
\vol(R)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(b_i-a_i) \, .
$$
If $E\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, then the *outer measure* $\lambda^*(E)$ of $E$ is defined to be
$$
\lambda^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{R\in\mathcal C}\vol(R):\text{$\mathcal C$ is a countable collection of closed rectangles which covers $E$}\right\} \, .
$$
(For me, finite sets are countable. This is actually essential to the definition when $n=0$.)

Finally, if $E$ satisfies the *Carathéodory criterio*n, that $\lambda^*(A)=\lambda^*(A\cap E)+\lambda^*(A\cap E^c)$ for all $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, then we say that $E$ is *Lebesgue measurable*, and the *Lebesgue measure $\lambda(E)$ of $E$* is defined as $\lambda^*(E)$.

So what about the case $n=0$? This is just a matter of following the definitions carefully. First, a closed rectangle in $\mathbb R^0$ is a Cartesian product of zero sets, which is $\{()\}$, the set containing the empty tuple. The "volume" of this rectangle is the empty product $1$. There are two subsets of $\mathbb R^0$, namely $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb R^0=\{()\}$. The empty set is covered by the empty collection of closed rectangles, and $\sum_{R\in\varnothing}\vol(R)$ is the empty sum $0$. Thus, $\lambda^*(\varnothing)=0$. It is also routine to check that $\lambda^*(\{()\})=1$ (this time, the computation is less vacuous). Both $\varnothing$ and $\{()\}$ satisfy the Carathéodory criterion (there are four cases to consider in total), and so we find that $\lambda(\varnothing)=0$ and $\lambda(\{()\})=1$. Thus, as Didier mentions in the comments, in zero dimensions, the Lebesgue measure coincides with the counting measure.

While this might all sound very silly, I can think of one example where defining the zero-dimensional Lebesgue measure is marginally useful. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb R$, then the determinant of $A$ ought to equal the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of the image of the unit cube under $A$. The determinant of the $0\times 0$ matrix over $\mathbb R$ is $1$, which does indeed equal the Lebesgue measure of the image of $\{()\}$.